# Is AutoComplete working on WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I've a TextBox, can I autocomplete using 5 options that I've in a List?

It would be great if this could be done using Binding and XAML.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no standard auto complete control in WPF. You can [google](http://www.google.com.ua/search?q=autocomplete+wpf) for 3rd parties. But there is one very easy way to create simplistic auto complete control by slightly adjusting an editable `ComboBox` template:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True">
  <ComboBox.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
      <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" />
    </ControlTemplate>
  </ComboBox.Template>
  <TextBlock Text="Hello"/>
  <TextBlock Text="World"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Thanks Anvaka. Do you know if its possible use binding with your sample?

Comment: @Jaime sure. Just set 'ItemsSource' property to the collection of items.